# The definition of dense sets

Tags: metric-spaces, definition

I am confused with the definition of dense sets. By definition, a subset $S$ of a metric space $X$ is dense in $X$ if the closure of $S$ in $X$ is equal to $X$. By definition, this means that every point of $X$ is either in $S$ or a limit point of $S$. My question is that does this mean every point of $X$ is a limit point of $S$? This is the explanation I often see about the subset $S$ being dense in $X$. But if an arbitrary point of $X$ actually lies in $S$, how do we know it is a limit point of $S$? By definition, for a point $x$ of $S$ to be a limit point of $S$, every epsilon ball around $x$ has to contain a point of $S$ which is different from $x$. And I am not sure why this will hold for any metric space $S$.

I am aware that the definition of a point being a limit point of a set is different from the definition of a point being the limit of a sequence in that set. With the latter definition, for any point $x$ of a set $S$, we can just take the constant sequence $(x_n)=x$ and say $x$ is the limit of this sequence. But this is different from $x$ being a limit point of $S$. If someone knows the answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\{0,1\}$, with its usual topology. Then $X$ is a dense subset of itself. However, neither $0$ nor $1$ is a limit point. So,no, $S$ being a dense subset of $X$ does not mean that every point of $X$ is a limit point of $S$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Then, why do some people say that if S is dense in X, every point of X is a limit point of S? For instance, Wheeden says so in his book "Measure and Integral ". Also, does that mean there are two types of sets, one in which every point is a limit point of that set and the other in which there is some point which is not a limit point of that set?
If this is true, are there names distinguishing these two sets?

Comment: @KoheiMiyazaki My guess is that those who say that if $S$ is dense in $X$, every point of $X$ is a limit point of $S$ use a different concept of limit point. They define it simply as a point which is the limit of a sequence of elements of $S$.

Comment: The author I mentioned defines a limit point of a set as the limit point of a sequence of distinct points, which is equivalent to your definition. But thank you so much anyway.

Comment: Forget density.  Does every point in a set S *have* to be a limit point.  Well, not by *my* definition, but if we define a limit point to be a limit of a sequence in S then if $x_n = x\in S$ then $\lim x_n =x$ so by *that* definition it is.  Or maybee the mean every point of $X$ that *isn't* a point of $S$ is a limit point.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you so much for your reply. That was my understanding. However, I have a book ("Measure and Integral by Wheeden") in which the author defines a limit point of a set S as the limit point of a sequence of distinct points of S, which is equivalent to your definition of limit points. But a coupe of lines after he says that if S is dense in X, then every point of X is a limit point of S, which confuses me. Do you know if there is a name for sets in which every point is a limit point of itself?

Comment: @KoheiMiyazaki The concepts agree if $X$ has no *isolated points*.

Comment: Some texts use "accumulation" points.  "Isolated points" are the only points in a set that are not ny definition of limit points. An isolated point is "by itself" and not "next to any point".

Answer (score 0):

"My question is that does this mean every point of X is a limit point of S?"

Not unless every point of $S$ is a limit point of $S$.  So to get a counter example take any set of $S$ which has points that aren't limit points of $S$.

A point $x\in S$ that is *not* a limit point.  Is such that there exists a value $r$ so that for any point $y \in S; y \ne x$ then $d(x,y) \ge r$.  In other words $x$ is a *singleton*.

So if $S$ has singletons that is a counter example.